# High current draw effect on low current components?

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, circuit-protection

Suppose i have a circuit like so:

`High Capacity PSU +............... 100mA component (CA) .............. 5A component (CB)
     |                                        |                                   |
     - .......................................................................... -`

CA is a device with lower current rating (100mA) than CB (with 5A rating). Suppose CB draws current while CA is operating. Will the high current burn CA? If so what would remedy this problem?

Comment: Are they connected in parallel? Provide a schematic of the circuit if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be suggesting a circuit like this.  The question is whether the high current of the right load will effect the left load.

The answer is no.  The amount of current of the right load will not cause the left load to have a high current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZRMYd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The only effect that could happen to cause a problem is if the high current load were to cause the voltage input to the low current load to drop.  This could cause noise on the low current circuit.
If you want to avoid issues such as this, you can use a star topology back to the source like below.  Now they do not share current paths.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frgLWb.png)</sup>